# jquery / javascript for upload the file from browser to server

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-2, file-upload

I am developing the application in asp.net mvc with c#. I want the functionality that , a div will popup, so that i can facilate to use to upload the image file from his browser to server  , in application domains file system. as usual. This question may be repeat , but i expect something more like

1. how to build this scenario, and what are the security issues may come?
2. and what care have to take while coding in the security perspective ?

Comment: Those are multiple questions, could you split them and ask them one by one, please ;)

Comment: yes, Edited. please review question

Comment: any updates here ? Or anybody have idea to post the form by javascript ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can ask multiple questions in 'step-by-step' format